# iOS auto layout : Display the cell only after its contents are updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I use auto layout and display a table with custom dynamic cells. Basically table displays chat between 2 persons. Thus, text message varies for each cell.

The issue here is that first cells are displayed and then within a second, its contents are resized. This is clearly visible and looks bad.

See below images to get idea of how it looks before and after resizing.

**Before resizing :**

[image]

**After resizing :**

[image]

I know there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925247/setneedslayout-relayouts-the-cell-only-after-is-has-been-displayed) on SO, but its answer does not really satisfy the need. I want to avoid overriding `layoutSubviews()` method as I don't think its a good enough solution.

I tried below code to unhide cell's `contentView` once they are displayed. But it does not work.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // At the begining
    cell.contentView.hidden = NO;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    // Before returning cell
    cell.contentView.hidden = YES;
    return cell;
}
```

Is there a way to delay displaying cell until they are resized to fit their contents?

UPDATE :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CHAT_CELL_IDENTIFIER];

        cell.textString.text = ...;
        cell.textString.frame = ...;
        cell.timeLabel.text = ...;                                             // set timeLabel to display date and time

        cell.userLabel.text = ...;       // set userLabel to display userName

        if (displaying cell where message is sent by user)
        {
            // Set image for sender
            cell.chatCellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleMine.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:STRETCHED_WIDTH topCapHeight:STRETCHED_HEIGHT];

            cell.chatCellBackground.frame = ...;

        }
        else
        {
            // set bubble for receiver
            cell.chatCellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleSomeone.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:STRETCHED_WIDTH topCapHeight:STRETCHED_HEIGHT];

            cell.chatCellBackground.frame = ...;
        }
    }

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where are you loading the content of the cell? This should be done in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @ClintWarner I do that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method only. I just have not added it in question.

Comment: What happens if you call layoutIfNeeded on the cell?

Comment: There is no reason why you should need to delay displaying the cell until the subviews resize to fit their contents. If everything is happening correctly, the cell and all of its subviews should have their content set and should layout and resize well in advance of the first time the cell and its view hierarchy draw onscreen. It's going to be difficult to help you debug where something has gone wrong though without seeing more of your code.

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira I already call it. Please check the code I added to my question.

Comment: @smileyborg I have added of method cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: check this it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614178/tableview-showing-the-wrong-size-of-cell

Comment: @smileyborg I have made changes to code and asked new question that I face with new code. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474157/uitableview-cell-contents-not-displayed-properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added below method in custom `UITableViewCell`'s class.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat maxTextWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.40;
    self.userLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxTextWidth;
    self.chatMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxTextWidth;
    self.timeLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.timeLabel.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

I also found that returning exactly right height of cell in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method is crucial.

**Hint :**

1. If height of any view is greater than expected then possibly calculated height of cell is greater than what is actually required.
2. If any of views is shrinking vertically or not displaying whole content then possibly calculated height of cell is lesser than what is actually required.

Yoy can test if height is wrong by adding/removing constant value to height (variable) you calculate for cell.