# UITableView cell contents not displayed properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I use auto layout and want to display `UITableView` with custom cell that has a `UITextView` with variable content.

Cells are displayed as shown below. For chat message, when cell is first displayed *only 2-3 characters are displayed in a single line* and next characters are forced to go to next line. But when I scroll tableView so that these cells are not visible and scroll back to make them visible (I do this so that when they are visible again cellForRowAtIndexPath: method is called again to render the cell), they render the cell properly as shown in second image.

[image]
[image]

**Code :**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [chatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RS_User *user = [[RS_User alloc]init];
    chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CHAT_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    cell.chatCellBackground.image = nil;

        NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:TEXT];       // get text string(message) from array

        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
        cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];        // set text font
        cell.textString.text = chatText;

        // set text
        CGSize size = [cell.textString.text sizeWithFont:cell.textString.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SET_WIDTH, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
        cell.textString.frame = ...;
        [cell.textString sizeToFit];

        NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:DATE];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:DATE_FORMAT];
        NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
        cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;                                             // set timeLabel to display date and time
        cell.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:SMALL_FONT_SIZE];

        cell.userLabel.text = @"Name";//[[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:NAME];       // set userLabel to display userName

        CGSize size1 = [cell.userLabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SET_WIDTH, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

        // check cell contains sender name or receiver name
        if (thisCellIsForSender)
        {
            // Set bubble for sender
            cell.chatCellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleMine.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:STRETCHED_WIDTH topCapHeight:STRETCHED_HEIGHT];
            cell.chatCellBackground.frame = ...;
        }
        else
        {
            // set bubble for receiver
            cell.chatCellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleSomeone.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:STRETCHED_WIDTH topCapHeight:STRETCHED_HEIGHT];
            cell.chatCellBackground.frame = ...;
        }

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RS_User *user = [[RS_User alloc]init];
    chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CHAT_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    cell.chatCellBackground.image = nil;

    NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:TEXT];       // get text string(message) from array

    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
    cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];        // set text font
    cell.textString.text = chatText;

    // set text
    CGSize size = [cell.textString.text sizeWithFont:cell.textString.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SET_WIDTH, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    cell.textString.frame = ...;
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];

    NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:DATE];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:DATE_FORMAT];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;                                             // set timeLabel to display date and time
    cell.timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:SMALL_FONT_SIZE];

    cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:NAME];       // set userLabel to display userName

    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

    CGSize size1 = [cell.userLabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SET_WIDTH, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

    // check cell contains sender name or receiver name
        if (thisCellIsForSender)
        {
            // Set bubble for sender
            cell.chatCellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleMine.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:STRETCHED_WIDTH topCapHeight:STRETCHED_HEIGHT];
            cell.chatCellBackground.frame = ...;
        }
        else
        {
            // set bubble for receiver
            cell.chatCellBackground.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleSomeone.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:STRETCHED_WIDTH topCapHeight:STRETCHED_HEIGHT];
            cell.chatCellBackground.frame = ...;
        }

    cell.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell.bounds));

    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];

    return cell.bounds.size.height;        
}
```

**UPDATE :** I could solve some of the issues from `coverback`'s answer. Still cell is not laid out correctly. I am adding photos for constraints of each UI object in cell.

**User name :**

[image][image]

**Time stamp :**

[image][image]

**Chat message :**

[image][image]

**Bubble image :**

[image][image]

**Cell Layout :**

- Cell height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is always 100 even though I return different value from `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Cell height in storyboard is 100.
- Chat message in third cell is clipped from bottom.
- Time stamps and chat message labels are some time not aligned properly to each other even though both have constraint `vertical spacing from username label`.
- Username label in third cell is vanished.

[image]

Do you see anything wrong in constraints? You can ask me if analyzing constraints is difficult.

Comment: cell.textString.frame not wotking, change cell.textString frames in chatCell class

Comment: Please update also the code, now that it is without the frames, as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the answers by thandasoru and coverback solved my issue. Below is the code I use.

I added below method in custom `UITableViewCell`'s class.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat maxTextWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.40;
    self.userLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxTextWidth;
    self.chatMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxTextWidth;
    self.timeLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.timeLabel.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

**UITableView datasource methods :**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell * cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCellId"];
    // Set all label's text and image to ImageView
    ...

    // Update layout
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customCell * cell = (customCell *)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString * userName = cell.userLabel.text;
    NSString * chatText = cell.chatMessage.text;

    // Get bounding rect of userName label
    CGRect userNameFrame = [userName boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxLabelWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.userLabel.font} context:nil];

    // Get bounding rect of chatMessage label
    CGRect chatTextFrame = [chatText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxLabelWidth, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.chatMessage.font} context:nil];

    // Calculate cell height from its contents
    height = userNameFrame.size.height + chatTextFrame.size.height + PADDING_ABOVE_TOP_LABEL + DISTANCE_BETWEEN_TWO_LABELS + PADDING_BELOW_BOTTOM_LABEL;

    return height;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the cell height dynamically so that the text appears on one line. I've given CGSize(320,568) as bounds. But you can change the size as you see fit

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:TEXT];
    CGRect frame = [chatText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(320,568) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f]} context:nil];
    return frame.height; //returns cell's height after calculating the area that text needs
}
```

Comment: I don't want text to appear on single line. I want it to use at most 60% of width of screen. Then next chars can go to next line.

Comment: I think you can change that inside CGSizeMake

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the frame of the text and calling `sizeToFit`:

```
    CGSize size = [cell.textString.text sizeWithFont:cell.textString.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(SET_WIDTH, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    cell.textString.frame = ...;
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];
```

**This will not be working with autolayout.** You need to remove setting the frame and `sizeToFit` completely, same goes for all other frame being set directly. If things don't work after that, it would mean some constraints are not correct. But mixing approaches always breaks layout.

For `UILabel`s, make sure to also set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to label's width, otherwise text may not wrap correctly:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.label.frame.size.width;
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Also, your height calculating method should not just do same thing as `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, if you want to use the same code, just call that other method to get a cell.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. These are helpful. It helped me solve few issues. Jerk problem is solved but cell is not laying out perfectly. I think issues can be in constraints. I'll update question to show constrains of each UI object.